# Error The current path, didn't match any of these

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to save the data submitted on a form, and redirect the user to a results.html.

------- Front template -------------------

## Welcome to readability test V1

```
<form action="/addtext" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="title"/>
    <input type="text" name="content"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Add"/>
</form>
```

**---------- URLS.PY -----------------**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from readtest.views import readtest, addtext


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('readability-test/', readtest),
    path('results/', addtext),
enter code here
```

**------------ VIEWS.PY ------------------------**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import TestedText
# Create your views here.

def readtest(request):
    return render(request, 'test.html')


def addtext(request):
    a = TestedText(title=request.POST['title'], content=request.POST['content'])
    a.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/results/')
```

**------ ERROR IM GETTING ------------------**
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/addtext
Using the URLconf defined in redability.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
readability-test/
results/
**The current path, addtext, didn't match any of these.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your urls.py file line `path('results/', addtext)` to `path('addtext/', addtext)`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from readtest.views import readtest, addtext


urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('readability-test/', readtest),
        path('addtext/', addtext),
```

Comment: Ok that fixed the saving the input to the model, I also fix the redirect part and changed with a render. def addtext(request):
    a = TestedText(title=request.POST['title'], content=request.POST['content'])
    a.save()
    return render(request, 'results.html')